# calculate auto exposure in openCv

Tags: opencv, histogram

I have a software working with an industrial grade camera with a manual lens (focus and aperture to be set manually).

I can control the cameras exposure time and gain. 
I did some histogram analysis to check the exposure of the image.
No I am looking for a method to transfer the mean value of the grayscale intensity into a exposure value.
Goal is to calculate a exposure time for a fixed aperture setting and a currunt lighting condition since the exposure value is Ev = Av + Tv (Av aperture value or f stops, Tv time value, exposure time) I hope that there is some conversion from grayscale intensity into Exposure value.

Comment: This answer may be most applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851988/adjusting-exposure-brightness-contrast-based-on-histogram-using-python

Answer (score 3):

I would like to give you my solution.

What I have found out is that normal cameras or not cabable of measuring brightness. In general an image sensor cannot distingish between bright colors as white and brithness circumstances.

Anyway, I implemented an historgram which is measuring the greyscale intensity. After that the mean value is extracted and scaled to a value range of 256. The goal is to have mean value of 128.

So I use the measured histogram mean value as input for a PI controller which controlls the the exposure time.

So this way I create a link between histogram mean value and exposure time

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to consider the histogram as providing the dynamic range required. Ansel Adams, and others, sometimes referred to this as Zones. So your 18% is Zone V (5). If your image has dynamic range that is clipping the high value (255) or clipping on the minimum (O), then you may need 2 or more images... One with less Ev at a high f# or less exposure to be unclipped ("blown out" think photo speak), and the another shot with more exposure to ensure that shadow detail is not lost ("blocked" in photo speak).

If you have an image that is within the 1-255 range, then you could rescale the image to have a mean value of 18%. Or have some calibration for light reading to exposure or Ev.

Generally you want the histogram both for computing then mean (EV or crestfactor) as well as a way to find the min/max in order to determine is you need more exposure/gain or less.

Of course if your picture is flat with respect to brightness, the. 128 is perfect. If there are a few bright sources and in general a "normal scene" then some mean value closer to 18% is statistically better (~46)